# What is the word to describe a (fully competent) translator's inability to translate the exact sense?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Translators are often at a loss to exactly translate a word, phrase or even an entire sentence because the source language and the target language are so far removed from each other culturally and linguistically.

For example, there seems to be no English equivalent for the Marathi concept, "Vihin Bai". It refers to the relationship between the mothers of the man and the woman who are/are going to be married. Since the concept does not exist in the same form in English-speaking societies, there's probably no equivalent.

What I need to find out is whether there is a word to describe the translator's inability to translate such culture-specific terms.

Comment: I don't think it is the inability of a translator, but simply the fact that there are words or expressions  that are literally untranslatable.

Comment: Related: [Is there a word that describes the information gap due to a reader's cultural bias across place and time?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/383812/191178)

Comment: If I vote to close this question as a duplicate, it will be closed immediately because I have a gold badge in SWRs... so, here's the link if anyone is interested: [What would you call a word that doesn't exist in or translate well into another language?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138289/what-would-you-call-a-word-that-doesnt-exist-in-or-translate-well-into-another)

Comment: @Josh 'Translator's inability to' means 'Translator's not being able to'. Usain Bolt is not able to run 100 metres in 2 seconds. OP clearly shows he understands this in his first sentence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Despite rep-capping a week running on a SWR question, I've yet to earn my SWR gold. Just shows how much work you've put in!

Comment: @DanBron also shows how much variety there is in the work *you've* put in. Also, is it possible that you've earned the highest score on not just ELU, but out of every language related stack exchange? I'm pretty sure nobody will any day soon break that record.

Comment: @Mari-LouA aha. That's interesting. Your answer is way better than _realia_ whatever. Let's see if I'm worthy to pick up that golden hammer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA On second thought, this is asking about the inability to translate, while your linked question asks about the words that are not translatable. So I'll put the  down.

Comment: You could use more commonplace terms such as saying the translator was *stuck* or *jammed* on the translation of a word.

Comment: @NVZ Oh, I see. I have the requisite tag rep, simply too few distinct answers. Well, that will come. I just need to wait for some interesting SWR questions.

Comment: As an aside, there is a related notion of *localization* which is not about translating the words used, but trying to convey in the new language and culture the same ideas and information expressed in the source.

Comment: @Hurkyl , thanks. That was what I wanted to talk about all along.

Comment: Voting to close.  Perhaps this could point to @Mari-LouA's suggestion: [What would you call a word that doesn't exist in or translate well into another language?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138289/what-would-you-call-a-word-that-doesnt-exist-in-or-translate-well-into-another) Reason for voting to close: Here, OP's premise is that the translator is perfectly competent.  Logically, this implies that the term or concept has no direct translation.

Comment: Mary LouA's question sounds in tune with mine. I am all for the closing.

Answer (score 4):

Even the most accomplished of translators can't work miracles: some things are inevitably **lost in translation.** -- [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lost+in+translation)

> Of a word or words, having lost or lacking the full subtlety of meaning or significance when translated from the original language to another, especially when done literally. (Usually formulated as "be/get lost in translation.")
>
> *My friend tried explaining a few French idioms to me, but I'm afraid they were lost in translation.*

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you for the input. I wonder if my answer is actually on point though. It's not a word for the said inability.

Comment: Wasn't required, but suit yourself.

Comment: @NikhilKhandekar it's not about suiting myself. The idea here is to be as helpful as possible in the knowledge I share. If it's not relevant to your question, either please explicitly mention what part of the answer can be changed or improved.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth being not a native speaker, whatever I add as a commentary will sound off putting to some speaker somewhere. Can you help rephrase it, or just flat out remove that part of the answer if you may. I will really appreciate that.

Comment: I don't know why these tactics are being used, in that case. If being helpful is the idea, I don't see how down votes are going to help you or me. Plus, of course, I have never stepped back. I stand by my words.

Comment: @NikhilKhandekar The idea of votes is to promote good answers. And downvotes mean "this post is not useful (as it is currently written). The must-follow rules is to be as relevant as possible. We have an option to edit posts, to continually improve. I do stand by my answer, the answer being "lost in translation".

Comment: wasn't referring to you, not at all. I just don't like the idea of administrators issuing such conditions, that's all. That first sentence in question was also misinterpreted, unfortunately.

Comment: @NikhilKhandekar no administrators were involved here. Just me, you, and another user who helped clear up potential misunderstandings before it's too late.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61402/discussion-between-nikhil-khandekar-and-nvz).

Comment: This string of comments is an illustration of the question -- and of the answer.

Comment: @ab2 yeah, I mean. No matter how fluent I think I am in the language, I will never have an ear like that of a native speaker.

Comment: @NVZ I am as puzzled as you are.

Comment: And they simply couldn't understand their own language, heh!